# Jquery to let my banner images load first before it animates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a banner image slideshow in jquery. Actually I just found the code somewhere, I can't remember. It starts to animate even the banner images are not yet fully loaded that makes the banner slideshow animates it's image description without images.

Anyone? please help me to modify the code and let it run by allowing the background images load first before it runs the slideshow animation.

Thank you.

```
(function ($) {
  // Original JavaScript code.
var currentBackground = 0;
var backgrounds = [];
backgrounds[0] = 'http://www.site.com/sites/all/themes/layoutph/images/bg01.jpg';
backgrounds[1] = 'http://www.site.com/sites/all/themes/layoutph/images/bg02.jpg';
backgrounds[2] = 'http://www.site.com/sites/all/themes/layoutph/images/bg03.jpg';
backgrounds[3] = 'http://www.site.com/sites/all/themes/layoutph/images/bg04.jpg';

var customtitle = [];
customtitle[0] = "Welcome to Site";
customtitle[1] = "Site joined force with Site Foundation";
customtitle[2] = "Site Foundation school campaigns for 2014";
customtitle[3] = "New York visited by Site Foundation";


function changeBackground() {
    if(currentBackground > 3 ) currentBackground = 0;
    currentBackground++;
    $('.masterbg').fadeOut(1000,function() {
         $('div.slogan').text( customtitle[currentBackground] );
        $('.masterbg').css({
            'background-image' : "url('" + backgrounds[currentBackground] + "')"
        });
        $('.masterbg').fadeIn(1000);
    });
    setTimeout(changeBackground, 4000);

}
     setTimeout(changeBackground, 4000);

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: create a [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/) demo

Answer (score 0):

```
    var UserimageObj = new Image();
    UserimageObj.src = "someimg.jpg";

    //load the user image before doing anything
    UserimageObj.onload = function () {

      //do your stuff here
    };
```

Is this what you were looking for?